# How can I make motor turn on automatically?

Tags: nodemcu

Here I am working on a smart irrigation project but I am unable to fix this problem as shown in below. Here I am trying to make it automatic but the motor does not turn off automatically it stays on forever.

This is the whole code:

https://kishan-ramesh.github.io/FREECODECAMP-PRODUCT-LANDING-PAGE./code.txt

I have tried else and if conditions but were not successful so pls help if you could. Thank YOU.

Comment: Turn on? or turn off? Title says on... Question says off...

Comment: I want to make it automatically in the code go down where I have commented the motor section

Comment: Please inlcude a minimal reproducible example of the code within the question itself, not on an external site.

Comment: Your code seem to be okay from the if/else condition point of view. The problem may come from the value being held by the `soilmoisturepercent` variable. Please edit your question to add the if/else motor condition and the implementation of the `map` lookup function (which gives you the value of `soilmoisturepercent`).